# ZK Framework Offline capability

Tags: client, offline, zk

Is there a possibility to store data offline on the client side with the ZK Framework? (see https://www.zkoss.org)

By data I mean for example **texts, pictures or videos** that I want to save locally if the client is offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ZK v8.5 there will be an [offline recovery feature of fragment component](http://blog.zkoss.org/2017/07/06/zk-8-5-preview-the-offline-recovery-feature-of-fragment-component/).

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.